# How to deploy my web application locally?

Tags: web-applications, glassfish, web-deployment, application-server

I am a bit confused with Application Server and deploying my web application on it. Say I have my own server at workplace. I understand how a web server works, I could simply install WAMP or XAMP and start my own web server, SQL server as well.

How do I start an application server? Say I want to start a glassfish server. How do I deploy my application on this web server / application server? This confusion has been a nightmare for me. Please help me bring some clarity around this subject.

Comment: first, xamp and wamp use Apache, not glassfish. However go to the httpd.conf of apache and set listening IP address to 0.0.0.0:80, instead of localhost

Comment: Hi! I never said XAMP and WAMP use glassfish. However; my overall question does surround more to a application server. I know how to configure Apache. Request you to read questions more carefully before commenting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Windows for this.

#### To start GlassFish:

1. Open a command prompt in your GlassFish home directory (where you unzipped or installed to, something like `C:\glassfish4`). You should see a "bin" folder in this directory.
2. Run `bin\asadmin start-domain` to start GlassFish. You will need to make sure that there is nothing running on ports 4848 or 8080, or you may see unusual behaviour.
3. Go to http://localhost:4848 to see the admin console starting up

#### To Deploy to GlassFish

1. The easiest way is to use the admin console. Click `Applications` on the left, then click `Deploy`. You will need to select the app from your local machine to be deployed. Most other settings can be left as default, but make sure there is a server in the `target` list.
2. Using the command line again; in the same directory as before in your command prompt, run `bin\asadmin deploy C:\path\to\MyApp.war`
3. Alternatively copy and paste your app to the `autodeploy` folder in your domain (the default domain is domain1): `C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy`. Once your app is in that folder, GlassFish should handle the rest (providing there are no problems with your app)

Answer (score 0):

Web application deployment instructions differ for different application servers.

Based on your question, I don't think what application server matter and I will use IBM Liberty Profile as an example.  You can download a free developer version from here (You can skip step 1 if you don't need eclipse),

https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-non-eclipse-environments/

And here are the instructions to deploy web application on Liberty Profile

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_dep_war.html